# HTTP Response 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END' Express JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

If I execute the following code, I am getting 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END' error.

```
    await db.collection("something").find({ "_id":value }).toArray(async function(err,result){
            await db.collection("something").find({}).toArray(function(err,ans){
                response.write("Something");
            });
        });
    response.end();
```

How to execute write and end methods in a sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mixing up waiting for `promise` using the `await` keyword and the `callback` syntax.

Once you add a `callback` function, in your case to the `toArray` function the signature changes and it no longer returns a `promise` hence you can't wait on it and your code executes in the wrong order.

So either use promise syntax:

```
let result = await db.collection("something").find({ "_id":value }).toArray();
let result2 =  await db.collection("something").find({}).toArray();
response.write("Something");
response.end();
```

Or just manage your callbacks better:

```
db.collection("something").find({ "_id":value }).toArray(async function(err,result){
    db.collection("something").find({}).toArray(function(err,ans){
        response.write("Something");
        response.end();
    });
});
```